# GROUP BY Time to a 24 hour day

Tags: sql

Given the following declarations where there is a registration of an arbitrary event for a user (USER) at a given time (TIME) in a table DATA:

```
CREATE TABLE DATA
(
  "USER" Varchar(20),
  "TIME" Time
);


INSERT INTO DATA ("USER", "TIME") VALUES ('Martin', '14:58:00.000');
INSERT INTO DATA ("USER", "TIME") VALUES ('Martin', '15:02:11.000');
INSERT INTO DATA ("USER", "TIME") VALUES ('Martin', '15:48:44.000');
INSERT INTO DATA ("USER", "TIME") VALUES ('Marion', '08:45:01.000');
INSERT INTO DATA ("USER", "TIME") VALUES ('Marion', '15:01:01.000');
INSERT INTO DATA ("USER", "TIME") VALUES ('Marion', '15:03:48.000');
```

It's trivial to find the number of events per user at a given one-hour period:

```
select 
    "USER", 
    extract(hour from "TIME") as "Hour",
    count(*)
from 
    DATA
group by
    "USER", 
    extract(hour from "TIME")
;
```

The result is, of course:

```
USER  |Hour|COUNT
------+----+-----
Marion|   8|    1
Marion|  15|    2
Martin|  14|    1
Martin|  15|    2
```

But how do I get the number of events per user across an entire day in one hour intervals? Like this:

```
USER  |Hour|COUNT
------+----+-----
Marion|   0|    0
Marion|   1|    0
...
Marion|   7|    0
Marion|   8|    1
Marion|   9|    0
...
Marion|  14|    0
Marion|  15|    2
Marion|  16|    0
...
Marion|  22|    0
Marion|  23|    0
Martin|   0|    0
Martin|   1|    0
...
Martin|  13|    0
Martin|  14|    1
Martin|  15|    2
Martin|  16|    0
...
Martin|  22|    0
Martin|  23|    0
```

BTW I won't have write access to any database involved.

Comment: What RDBMS please? And version?

Comment: I was thinking more generally and not RDBMS specific, thus my post under the tag sql, and not under some vendor specific. Say SQL-92.

Answer (score 5):

You would want to do something like this, create a (temp) table HOURS with the numbers 0 to 23, then do an outer join to get all the HOUR values regardless of whether they are in DATA

```
select 
    "USER", 
    extract(hour from "TIME") as "Hour",
    SUM(CASE WHEN Data.HOUR is NOT NULL 1 ELSE 0 END)
from 
    DATA
    right outer join HOURS on extract(hour from "TIME") = HOURS.hour
group by
    "USER", 
    extract(hour from "TIME")
;
```

If you can't create a table, you can do ugly things like

```
(SELECT 1 as hour UNION 2 ... UNION 23) as HOURS
```

though there might be better way to do this depending your dialect

Comment: You might want a column name in the first SELECT of your UNION example.

Comment: Also, do you need `COUNT(Data.User)` to account for the NULLs resulting from the OUTER JOIN?

Comment: @Dems - depends.  If we were in MySQL we'd have to something like a COALESCE, but given that I'm not sure what the dialect was, I left this out.

Comment: I mean... If there are no records to join on to HOURS, `COUNT(*)` will still return `1`, but `COUNT(Data.User)` will return `0`.

Comment: ah, it's a count, not a sum, sorry

Comment: Outer join'ing with a predefined hours list (be it from a table or union) will result i NULL's for the USER name for all hour intervals where there are no events for that user.

Comment: @Turin,Spinning_Plate : The OUTER JOIN will indeed result in NULL records against hours with no data.  The use of COUNT(*) would therefore give an incorrect value of 1.  The use of COUNT(Data.User), however, would give a result of 0 - as it does not include the NULL values.

Comment: @Dems Actually the missing user names is the real problem. spinning_plate's classic SUM..CASE..WHEN (or SUM..COALESCE if you like) will take care of the counting, but how do I get the user name?

Comment: @Turin - you could join the hours table to SELECT DISTINCT USER and the join on both the hour and the name.

Comment: @spinning_plate Yes, it ocurred to me 20 mins ago. An initial distinct cross join between users and hours to get the full matrix of (user, hour), followed by a left join on (user, hour) with the original count-per-user-per-hour fragment. 
I wonder why i didn't think of that from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

@spinning_plate's answer is good for a vertical answer (both ways -- temp table, or unions)

You might also like a horizontal result -- i.e. with headers: user | 0000 | 0100 | 0200 | ... | 2200 | 2300

If so, then some options...

with SQL-Server 2005+ or Oracle 11g+, look into `PIVOT / UNPIVOT`

with Oracle <11g, look into DECODE (e.g.:

```
SELECT
   ...
   SUM(DECODE(extract(hour from "TIME"),1,1,0)) as 0100,
   SUM(DECODE(extract(hour from "TIME"),13,1,0)) as 1300,
...
```

Comment: It's not a bad answer, but not what i was looking for. You'll get this from joining with an hours table: 

    USER  |Hour
    ------+----
    [null]|  0
    [null]|  1